# How convert a particular single character in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to convert a single character to lower or upper case in MySQL
if it occurs in a string
Like: "racecar" and I want to convert 'a' to upper should output "rAcecAr";

Here is my complicated query

```
SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING( [column], 1, locate("a", [column]) - 1 ), 
               UCASE(SUBSTRING( [column], locate("a", [column]), 1 )), 
               SUBSTRING( [column], locate("a", [column]) + 1, length([column]) ) 
        ) AS AAsCapital 
FROM [table] 
WHERE [column] LIKE "%a%" OR [column] NOT LIKE "%a%";
```

Comment: `LIKE '%a%' OR NOT LIKE '%a'` will match everything.

Comment: Try to use [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: @Barmar yes I want all columns even not contain 'a' in as substring

Comment: Then leave out the `WHERE` clause entirely.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't use `[]` around table and column names, that's used in SQL-Server.

Comment: @Luuk where and how I never use REPLACE() keyword can you help me to write complete query thanks

Comment: @Barmar I would guess that the `SUBSTRING`s were failing if there was no 'a' present in the column and that is why OP added the `WHERE` clauses

Comment: @Martin But the WHERE clause doesn't fix that, since it matches rows where the `LOCATE` fails.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed it doesn't but I suspect as part of an effort to 'get it working' OP first excluded all rows where there wasn't an 'a' and then tried to include them which causes it to not work

Comment: @Luuk sorry here [] I'm trying to show that [column] is table column name and [table] to table name

Comment: @Barmar that's not helping quite well reducing the query length thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've missed a complexity that isn't obvious, this is as simple as using [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace all `a` characters with uppercase:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(FIRST_NAME, 'a', 'A')
  FROM  myTable
  WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%a%'
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8jJE6RaGoCAyLaspEpReM4/0) that shows this in action.

Comment: Thanks, man you are awesome I'm trying on this for a long time again thanks